# How to add a subdomain to the exchange server 2013?

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange, domain, subdomain, exchange-2013

I have Exchange Server 2013 which handles our corporate email. The default emails looks like this `username@example.com`.

I need to add a sub domain to the servers so one email can look something like this `newUsername@subdomain.example.com`

Finally I need to setup the new email `newUsername@subdomain.example.com` as a catch all email for the sub domain.

I found a [good tutorial](http://www.techieshelp.com/create-a-catch-all-mailbox-in-exchange-2013/) that explain how to add a catch all rule to an email.

How can I add the sub domain `subdomain.example.com` to my Exchange 2013 server without causing problems to my main domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open EAC (Exchange Admin Center).

Select **Mail Flow** on the Left Panel Menu.

Select **Accepted Domains** from the Top Menu.

Click the **+** icon.

Enter a name in **Name**, enter the fqdn of the subdomain in **Accepted Domain**. ("subdomain.example.com").

Select **Authoritative domain**.

Select **Save**

Don't forget to add/update an MX record for the subdomain.

To confirm the setting use the powershell cmdlet `Get-AcceptedDomain`

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much. I will attempt to do this over the weekend "while everyone is out" and I will let you know