# Email sub-domains issue. Exchange server 2013

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013

in regards to a previous post. I am trying to achieve the same but coming up with an error and looking for some help.

Link to previous post:[How to add a subdomain to the exchange server 2013?](https://serverfault.com/questions/705802/how-to-add-a-subdomain-to-the-exchange-server-2013)

So I have done everything in that post. And when I try and send an email from one client to another, I get the error "The message can't be sent because at least one recipient is invalid."

I have added the MX records for the sub domain in DNS as a child domain and added it as an authoritative accepted domain inside the mail flow section.

When I run the command Get-AcceptedDomain, the sub domain shows up the same as the regular domain does with the only difference being the default section saying "False" as you can see in this puush image http://puu.sh/mVDq6/dd1cd658ad.png

Any help would be amazing! Any ideas at all! :D

Thanks!

Comment: Another image showing the error http://puu.sh/mVDHZ/80bc73fef6.png

Comment: Did you add the new domain to the email address policy? If not, you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You should only have one default and the subdomains are not
- Ensure the DC replication took place for your change if you have multiple DCs
- Ensure you have all domain & subdomain as part of your E-mail Address Policy
@knairn.com
@tech.knairn.com
@prod.knairn.com
Default might look like - **%g.%s@knairn.com**

[Configure Exchange to accept mail for multiple authoritative domains](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996314%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)
You should complete the Step1 and Step2 at the bottom of this MS article
Step1: Create an authoritative domain
Step 2: Configure an email address policy for the authoritative domain